# how to write onclick action from infowindow content in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, google-maps, onclick, infowindow

i am working on google maps in angular 4 project i need a click event inside the infowindow,how to write it??? i have tried with the following code but the name is undefined.i have called an action from content .but onclick is not firing .

component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as mapConfig from 'app/mapConfig';
import * as $ from 'jQuery';
declare var google: any;
let directionsDisplay;
let controller;
let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
let map;
let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
let infowindowSBV = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
   //styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    controller = this;
    this.getIntersectionInfo();

  }
 changeAQIMsg(markerId) {
    alert("hi");

  }
  getIntersectionInfo() {
    var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(39.721612, -104.990757);
    const mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: centerPoint,
      styles: mapConfig.styles
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapView'), mapOptions);
    let locations = [{
      "address": "1st Ave. & University Blvd", "imageUrl": "green.png", "boundVals": [23, 4, 56, 98],
      cords: [["39.718084, -104.951149", "39.718331, -104.966325"],
      ["39.719435, -104.959423", "39.717065, -104.959301"]
      ]
    },
    {
      "address": "Broadway & Evans Ave", "imageUrl": "green.png", "boundVals": [40, 78, 90, 100],
      cords: [["39.678637, -105.024993", "39.678402, -104.945545"], ["39.653162, -104.987572", "39.700528, -104.987418"]]
    },
    {
      "address": "Sheridan Blvd. & Florida Ave", "imageUrl": "green.png", "boundVals": [33, 77, 21, 20],
      cords: [["39.689494, -105.081548", "39.689576, -105.025077"], ["39.667798, -105.053284", " 39.710644, -105.053250"]]
    },
    {
      "address": "Sheridan Blvd. & Colfax Ave", "imageUrl": "green.png", "boundVals": [9, 67, 45, 32],
      cords: [["39.740217, -105.081354", "39.740289, -105.029863"], ["39.720488, -105.053286", "39.758467, -105.053239"]]
    },
    // {"address":"Sheridan Blvd. & Bear Valley Ctr","imageUrl":"green.png","boundVals":[12,78,54,90],
    // cords :[["39.711106, -104.912963","39.698666, -104.912913"],["39.707334, -104.922368","39.699063, -104.904904"]]} ,                  
    {
      "address": "Leetsdale Dr. & Monaco St. Pkwy", "imageUrl": "green.png", "boundVals": [5, 43, 19, 69],
      cords: [["39.678502, -104.912730", "39.718350, -104.912715"],
      // ["39.707334, -104.922368", "39.699063, -104.904904"]
      ["39.699063, -104.904904", "39.714650, -104.940265"]
      ]
    },
    {
      "address": "Federal Blvd. & Alameda Ave", "imageUrl": "green.png", "boundVals": [21, 32, 2, 87],
      cords: [["39.711292, -105.053252", "39.711133, -104.999028"], ["39.693152, -105.025057", "39.732973, -105.025200"]]
    },
    {
      "address": "Colorado Blvd. & Colfax Ave", "imageUrl": "green.png", "boundVals": [41, 53, 76, 89],
      cords: [["39.743777, -104.940779", "39.734093, -104.940771"], ["39.740223, -104.912868", "39.740193, -104.956158"]]
    },
    {
      "address": "Colorado Blvd. & Alameda Ave", "imageUrl": "green.png", "boundVals": [10, 22, 56, 87],
      cords: [["39.711132, -104.980963", "39.709036, -104.874922"], ["39.686325, -104.940595", "39.740020, -104.940600"]]
    }]
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    let markerURL = "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/";
    let plotMapCoords = [];
    let mapCords = [];
    for (let loc of locations) {
      for (let c of loc.cords) {
        if (plotMapCoords.length < 10) {
          plotMapCoords.push(c);
        } else {
          mapCords.push(c)
        }

      }
      console.log(plotMapCoords)
      console.log(mapCords)
      //plotMapCoords.push(c);

      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': loc.address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          let callMethod = "changeAQIMsg('gello ')";
          let content = '<div class="infoContent">'+
           '<div class="infoheading"><font size="+2" color="#000000">Location</font></div>'+
          '<div class="infoBody">'+
          '<div class="infoWindowAQI">'+
            '<div class="infoWindowTitle" id="infoWindowTitle">Springfield</div>'+
            '<div class="infoWindowAQIState" id="infoWindowAQIState">Moderate</div>'+
            '<div class="infoWindowAQILabel">Short-term AQI</div>'+
            '<div class="infoWindowAQIValue" id="infoWindowAQIValue">56</div>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="infoWindowAQIIndex">'+
          '<span class="infoWindowAQIIndexElement" (click)="'+callMethod+'" style="background-color: rgb(0, 228, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); ">Good</span>'+
          '<span class="infoWindowAQIIndexElement" (click)="this.changeAQIMsg("Moderate")" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Moderate</span>'+
          '<span class="infoWindowAQIIndexElement" (click)="this.changeAQIMsg("Warning")" style="background-color: rgb(255, 126, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ">Warning</span>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="infoWindowAQIMessage" id="infoWindowAQIMessage">'+
          'Air quality is acceptable; however, for some pollutants there may be a moderate health concern for a very small number of people who are unusually sensitive to air pollution'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="infoWindowTabs">'+
            '<div class="infoWindowTab" id="tab1">NB</div>'+
            '<div class="infoWindowTab" id="tab2">SB</div>'+
            '<div class="infoWindowTab" id="tab3">EB</div>'+
            '<div class="infoWindowTab" id="tab3">WB</div>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="infoWindowTabContent" id="tabContent">'+
          'sample data showing bound charts and values'
          '</div>'+
            '</div></div>';
          let icon = {
            url: "assets/images/sbvNewIcon.png", // url
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32), // scaled size
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
          };
          console.log(results[0].geometry.location)
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
              map: map,
              //title:loc.address,
              //icon:icon,
              icon: markerURL + loc.imageUrl,
              info: content,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (title) {
            //console.log(title);

            infowindow.close();
            infowindow.setOptions({
              pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-1, -25, 'px', 'px')
            });
            infowindow.setContent(marker.info);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });

        } else {
          alert("no location");
        }
      })
    }
    console.log(plotMapCoords)
    this.plotMap(plotMapCoords, "sbv");
    setTimeout(() => { this.plotMap(mapCords, "sbv") }, 8500);
    console.log()
    //setTimeout(()=>{this.plotBluetoad()},4000)



  }

function changeAQIMsg(markerId) {
    alert("hi");

  }
```

tried calling js function at the end but that also remains the same

Comment: Can you please add more content to your code. Its not clearly visible how you are adding the content to your component and how your component looks like.

Comment: hi gambo i have added my component file can u help me now

Comment: please can anyone answer my question ???need a solution

Comment: are you able to open infowindo?

Comment: yes but onclick action not firing

Answer (score 0):

To call a function you defined in you angular component from the google maps infowindow you simply need to do the following things:

1. in your constructor import NgZone

```
    constructor(public _ngZone: NgZone) {}
```

2. inside the function ngOnInit() save a reference of your component and NgZone to the window context

```
    window['angularComponentRef'] = { component: this, zone: this._ngZone };
```

3. From your infowindow html call your function like this

```
const markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: <div onclick="window.angularComponentRef.zone.run(() =>{window.angularComponentRef.component.yourFunction()})"> </div>,
});
```

Happy coding

Comment: Are there any security concerns with exposing the component in this way?