# Google Maps InfoWindow - (click) trigger an Angular 2 function

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, infowindow

I have a component that leverages google maps in an Angular 2+ app.  Is there a decent way to get a link into a marker's infowindow that will trigger a method in my component?  The `(click)` below is the trouble spot.  I can swap to `onclick` if I want to mess with making a global method (hoping to avoid that).

```
//Add directions if we have a current location
let additionalContent = "";
if(this.positionMarker){
  additionalContent = `<br><a href='#' (click)='startNavigating(${marker.position.lat()}, ${marker.position.lng()})'>Directions</a>`;
}

let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: content + additionalContent
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
  infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
});
```

Comment: i answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68253574/10087024 Greetings,
Dominik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a few pieces to make this work without crazy angular overhead.  The keys were to:

1. Only have 1 info window (member)
2. Add unique IDs to the anchor tags
3. When the infoWindow opens (`domready`), add a click listener to the anchor's id that was clicked

Code below:

```
//Add directions if we have a current location
let additionalContent = "";
if (this.positionMarker) {
  additionalContent = `<br><a href='#' id='marker_${markerId}'>Directions</a>`;
}

//Add the marker listener to open the infowindow
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
  this.infoWindow.setContent(content + additionalContent);
  this.infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);

  //Once infow window is open, add a click listener based on the ID in the anchor tag
  if (additionalContent) {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.infoWindow, 'domready', () => {
      document.getElementById(`marker_${markerId}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.startNavigating(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
      });
    });
  }
});
```